# When I open a specific website, I am switched to my router’s password web page. Why does this happen?

Tags: router, apache-http-server, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening a specific website switches me to my router’s password web page](https://superuser.com/questions/97191/opening-a-specific-website-switches-me-to-my-routers-password-web-page)

My router is Huawei MT880. When I open the my website that i m hosting, a dialog box asking for my router password appears. I am also using Apache webserver for publishing my own website. I have also register a free domain, that is pointing to my routers IP.

Comment: What "specific website"?

Comment: Same user, samer question: http://superuser.com/questions/97191/opening-a-specific-website-switches-me-to-my-routers-password-web-page

Answer (score 1):

It could be a mis-configured website, which is issuing a redirect to a private IP address which happens to be the same as the private IP address of your router.

Comment: u mean, if  I ping the website, i m pinging to my router's IP ??

Comment: Not necessarily. It'd be the webpage doing the redirect most likely, so a ping to the website server could actually ping the website and not your router.

Comment: A webserver has a concept of it's address, and it will use that address when it needs to do a redirect, so you could be entering "http://example.com/directory", this is getting a redirect to "http://192.168.0.1/directory/", which your router is grabbing. Just a theory...

Comment: i noticed that when I open the website with "www." as in "www.example.com", it redirect me to the routers page. But if id open it without "www" as in just "example.com", the website is opened? any reason ??

Comment: That sounds like EXACTLY what I'm talking about.

Comment: if it is the problem of the website or my router ?? because i also can't open the "ftp.example.com" ftp server of the website ?? i there ant cure for this which i an apply ??

Comment: It's the website. Likely on one can go there. Can you tell us the website and we could just test it?